# Why does the recursion goes to else block instead of if?

Tags: java, recursion, methods

```
class myclass {
   static int fun(int a[],int n){
      int x;

      if(n == 1){
        return a[0];
      }
      else{
           x = fun(a, n-1);

          if(x > a[n-1])
              return x;
          else
             return a[n-1];
      }
}
 public static void main(String[] args){
     int arr[] = {12, 10, 30, 50, 100};
     System.out.println(fun(arr, 5));}
}
```

Why is the output 100 and not 12 . I am not getting why the last recursive call when the value of n is 1 , it is going to else block instead of if .

Comment: If you indent your code logically there is more chance of anyone figuring out what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: The gentleman is new, why did somebody have to vote him down, that seems unnecessary. SO says they want to make this place more friendly to new comers so please be nice or at least constructive.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're looking for *maximum* in the array. Changing `if(x > a[n-1])` to `if(x < a[n-1])` will make your program return 10 for given input.

Comment: Given the time of year, two thirds though a second semester in programming,  I bet he is a student learning recursion and you might have given him the answer to his homework.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you return at the end to the prior instance of the same function, thus your method calls and returns look like this (each level indentation is a function call and its return). If you know how to use a debugger, step though your code and see and draw this diagram as you go, this will help you be able to mentally visualize the recursive calls and the values returned each time.

```
fun(a[],5) 
 |   fun(a[],4) 
 |   |   fun(a[],3)
 |   |   |  fun(a[],2)
 |   |   |   |  fun(a[],1)
 |   |   |   |  return 12
 |   |   |   return 12
 |   |   return 30
 |   return 50
 return 100
```

Comment: It looks fine to me, what do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Oh I see it two twelves and not a 10, I wonder if that was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

1. N=1 , x= 12 , 12 >  a[0] (12) ---> return a[1-1] = 12
2. N=2.  x=12 , 12 > a[1] (10) --> return x = 12;
3. N=3.  x=12, 12> a[2] (30) --> return a[3-1] = 30
4. N =4 x =30, 30 > a[3] (50) --> return a[4-1] = 50
5. N=5  x =50 , 50 > a[4] (50) ---> return a[5-1] = 100

Answer (score 0):

Here in details why the result is **100**.

```
public class myclass {
 static int fun(int a[],int n)
{
 int x;
 if(n == 1)
{
 return a[0];   // Step (2) --> return x = 12, now again n = 5 then continue on line        
}
 else
{
 x = fun(a, n-1); // Step (1) --> this line is same as x = fun(a, 1)
 if(x > a[n-1])     // Step (3) --> at this point n = 5 again and x = 12 while a[4] = 100 which is not less than x, statement 12 > 100 is false, move on to else block
 return x;
 else
 return a[n-1];  // Step (4) --> return a[4] which is 100 as see above
}
}
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
 int arr[] = {12, 10, 30, 50, 100};
 System.out.println(fun(arr, arr.length));}
}
```

Hopefully, you will understand what you have been missing on your recursion example!